# jquery jtable Actions not sending $_POST data

Tags: php, jquery, post, jquery-jtable

I can't seem to get the Actions working in `jTable`. I'm trying to get a record to delete but it keeps saying `An error occured while communicating to the server.` When I send the ID via `$_GET` it works, so it seems that it's not sending the `POST` data properly. Does anyone have any experience with this? Thanks a lot!

Here is the table script:

```
            $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
                paging: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                sorting: true,
                defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
                create: true,

                title: 'Manage Students',
                actions: {
                    listAction: 'listStudentsXHR.php?action=list',
                    createAction: 'createStudentsXHR.php?action=create',
                    updateAction: '',
                    deleteAction: 'deleteStudentsXHR.php?action=delete'
                },
                fields: {
                    userID: {
                        create: false,
                        title: 'ID',
                        key: true,
                        width: '3%'
                    },
                    username: {
                        title: 'Username',
                        width: '10%'
                    },
                    password: {
                        title: 'Password',
                        list: false,
                        type: 'password'
                    },
                    password_confirm:{
                        title: 'Confirm Password',
                        list: false,
                        type: 'password'
                    },
                    firstName: {
                        title: 'First Name',
                        width: '10%'

                    },
                    lastName: {
                        title: 'Last Name',
                        width: '10%'
                    },
                    points: {
                        create: false,
                        title: 'Points',
                        width: '10%'
                    },
                    level: {
                        create: false,
                        title: 'Level',
                        width: '5%'
                    },
                    status: {
                        create: false,
                        title: 'Status',
                        width: '10%'
                    },
                    curriculum: {
                        create: false,
                        title: 'Curriculum',
                        width: '10%'
                    },
                    numberCell: {
                        title: 'Cell Number',
                        width: '10%'
                    },
                    email: {
                        title: 'Email',
                        width: '10%'
                    },
                },


            });
            $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load');
```

Here is the PHP file it's sending to for the delete action:

```
try {
    require_once("includes/functions.php");
    require_once("includes/session.php");
    confirm_logged_in();
    require_once("includes/db_connection.php");

    if($_GET["action"] == "delete") {
        $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['userID']);

        //DELETE record from database
        $query = "DELETE FROM user WHERE userID = {$user_id})";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die('ERROR: '.mysqli_error());

        //Return result to jTable
        $jTableResult = array();
        $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
        print json_encode($jTableResult);

    }

} catch(Exception $ex) {
    //Return error message
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "ERROR";
    $jTableResult['Message'] = $ex->getMessage();
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`updateAction: ''`
please mention the url of the code that is to be run. Leaving it empty causing this issue

Answer (score 0):

You must use `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST` for getting a value which is sent via `post` method, you are using `$_GET` in your php code, I changed your `php` code, try this

```
try {
    require_once("includes/functions.php");
    require_once("includes/session.php");
    confirm_logged_in();
    require_once("includes/db_connection.php");

    if($_REQUEST["action"] == "delete") {
        $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_REQUEST['userID']);

        //DELETE record from database
        $query = "DELETE FROM user WHERE userID = {$user_id})";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die('ERROR: '.mysqli_error());

        //Return result to jTable
        $jTableResult = array();
        $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
        print json_encode($jTableResult);

    }

} catch(Exception $ex) {
    //Return error message
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "ERROR";
    $jTableResult['Message'] = $ex->getMessage();
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I tried this however, it still returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The default Jtable actions are sent using `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`. This might be the reason why you are getting the error.